# Convert TextBox string to Byte

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

how to convert TextBox string value to Byte. I have:

```
     array<Byte>^ mybytes = gcnew array<Byte>{6,2,1}; 
     mybytes[1] = motor1ForwardTextBox->Text->System::IConvertible::ToByte;
     System::Diagnostics::Debug::Write(mybytes[1]);
```

but there is error in second line:

```
Error   2   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char (__clrcall System::IConvertible::* )(System::IFormatProvider ^)' to 'unsigned char'   c:\users\guest4\documents\avr\serial2\serial2\Form1.h   563 1   serial2 (Visual Studio 2010)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way is:

```
mybytes[1] = Byte::Parse(motor1ForwardTextBox->Text);
```

After all, the nature of the conversion you want is *parsing* decimal digits.

Either way you'll get exceptions if the characters are not digits with optional + and -, or the value is not in the range 0 to 255. And, unfortunately, even though parsing to Byte does not accept "," or ".", the acceptable digit characters do depend on the culture. So, if necessary, pass an IFormatProvider.

Answer (score 1):

String does an explicit implementation of the [`IConvertible::ToByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355898.aspx) method, so you'll need to cast it.

And of course, you'll need to actually call the method. That error message is saying that it can't convert from a method that returns unsigned char, to an unsigned char.

```
mybytes[1] = dynamic_cast<IConvertible^>(motor1ForwardTextBox->Text)->ToByte();
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                    ^^
```